# Many Numpy Arrays vs Few Python Classes

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'm working on a project that heavily relies on reasonably small 2D Numpy arrays to represent our data (where small is around 100 x 4, at worst). The problem with this representation is that is extremely cumbersome and unclear given the context of the problem, terrible to maintain, and very bug prone. For example, my current task, in the context of these arrays, requires adding and removing multiple rows, and allocating a large number of them. I decided that an object-oriented, graph-based approach would be far clearer to use on my end and more generic for future development. After sitting down and designing most of the functionality on paper, there will probably be 5 or 6 larger classes with internal dictionaries (representing adjacency lists for graphs), that remove the need for Numpy arrays and are much clearer to interpret.

It is well known that Numpy arrays blow Python data structures out of the water in terms of  indexing speed and most other functionality. However, I also know that Python dictionaries are highly optimized and are fairly efficient in their own right. My dilemma is whether or not reallocating many Numpy arrays and copying values back and forth is more or less efficient than a few persisting classes that can be edited easily without reallocation, but will have slower indexing time than a Numpy array.

It's worth noting that I'm not using much of Numpy functionality other than `np.where()`, which can be worked around if necessary. Also the algorithm scales not in the size of arrays but in the *number* of arrays; a harder problem will have more arrays, but not necessarily larger ones.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered performance analysis (profiling, etc.)?

Comment: In terms of deciding which method is more efficient? It will take a week or two to get the OOP solution up and running fully, and I'm trying to evaluate whether that time is worth investing.

Comment: Who said numpy arrays are faster than python data structures? Depends on what you're doing and how you access the data.

Comment: It seemed to be the general consensus from what I could find. I'd be delighted to wrong; it means I can have fast readable code :)

Comment: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" - complex and difficult code comes a close second - start with the simple clear approach and see if you need to optimise then profile and hit the points that will give the most benefit possibly with some Cython or C.

Comment: You don't need to get it *"up and running fully"*, just enough to see whether the bottleneck operations are going to be a killer. If you're not using matrix operations much you may not be getting the most of `numpy`. Bear in mind too that there are other aspects; having a more intuitive model will affect further development and maintenance time, as you comment. We can't tell you whether that's critical for whatever your use case is.

Comment: Why can't you just wrap the numpy arrays in a class, rather than changing the data-structure?

Comment: jonrsharpe - the numpy arrays are embodying a weird condensed way to represent a graph my research group came up with two years ago that is now out of date. All of the related algorithms are built on top of that data structure, so it's nontrivial (at least from what I can see) to just test the bottlenecks.

Future development is important, since I'm the sole developer at this point. It'd be ideal if someone can take up the mantle at some point, but is clarity worth a performance hit? I feel like the answer is probably yes, but I'm trying to see how big of a tradeoff this would be.

Comment: user3467349 - the numpy arrays are wrapped in a class, but the operations that need to be done on the arrays need to be rewritten and involve many reallocations and data copying.

Comment: Steve Barnes - I think you're right. A clear working model with room for improvement is ideal.

Comment: There's always a tradeoff... sure, you don't want to optimize prematurely, but you also don't want to spend a week writing code that has a good chance of being too slow for your needs. Numpy can be unreadable when compared to pure python, but you can stuff the borderline-unreadable bits into small functions or classes that are named and documented well. It can be difficult, but I'd try to guess what parts of the algorithm will be the bottleneck and do a back-of-the-envelope calculation as to whether the factor of 10-100 speedup you get with numpy will be noticeable.

Comment: Steve Barnes raised a good point about Cython. Clear but slow Python code could be ran through Cython and ultimately get the best of both worlds.

Comment: If your number of arrays is very large, you could take a look at ``tables`` (http://www.pytables.org/), which allows you to organize arrays in hierarchical structures. As a bonus, you'll get a data viewer GUI (http://vitables.org/).

Comment: I think I'm going to take Steve Barnes' advice and rewrite a clear usable and maintainable implementation of my code, profile and optimize the Python code as much as possible, then use Cython to get the performance I really need. Unless anyone has any better ideas, of course.